# R - How to use rollapply on functions from other package like maxdrawdown from tseries?

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to use `rollapply` from zoo package with function `maxdrawdown` from tseries package:

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,10,8,6,5,4,6,7,8)
y <- zoo(x)
z <- rollapply(y,3,maxdrawdown,fill=NA,align="right")
```

However I get this error message:

```
Error in zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) : 
 “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
```

Does that mean I cannot use `rollapply` on function `maxdrawdown`? Is there alternative solution to work this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxdrawdown` returns a list but we just want the `maxdrawdown` component of that list so try this:

```
rollapplyr(y, 3, function(x) maxdrawdown(x)$maxdrawdown, fill = NA)
```