# Does rollapply() allow an array of results from call to function?

Tags: r, zoo

```
# Loading packages

require(forecast)
require(quantmod)

# Loading OHLC xts object

getSymbols('SPY', from = '1950-01-01')

# Selecting weekly Close prices

x <- Cl(to.weekly(SPY))

# ARIMA(p,d,q) estimation and forecasting function

a.ari.fun <- function(x) {

  a.ari <- auto.arima(x = x, d = 1, max.p = 50, max.q = 50, max.P = 50,
                      max.Q = 50, ic = 'aic', approximation = TRUE)
  fore <- forecast.Arima(object = a.ari, h = 4, level = c(.9))
  supp <- tail(fore$lower, 1)
  rest <- tail(fore$upper, 1)
  return(c(supp, rest))

}

# Roll apply ARIMA(p,d,q) in rolling window

rollapplyr(data = tail(x, 800), width = 750, FUN = a.ari.fun)
```

This code returns me an error because of

```
return(c(supp, rest))
```

at the end of `a.ari.fun()` function I wrote; I'm sure about that because if `a.ari.fun()` returns just

```
return(rest)
```

it works fine.

How do I have to arrange the `a.ari.fun()` in order to obtain an object suitable to `rollapplyr()`?

Comment: what do you expect the output to look like?  Can you use rollapply twice?  Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942884/r-how-to-use-rollapply-on-functions-from-other-package-like-maxdrawdown-from-t) will give you some ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately it takes lot of time to complete all the iterations, I cannot afford to duplicate waiting time; the result I would like is a matrix with _n_ rows and 2 columns: the first column contains 'supp' time series, while the second one contains 'rest' time series.

Comment: It looks like exactly the opposite of the post you linked: that friend had a multiple output result and he needed just a single value; I would need the opposite, i.e. a multiple value output :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like using `by.column=FALSE` will give what you request.

```
tail(rollapplyr(data = as.zoo(x), width = 750, FUN = a.ari.fun, by.column=FALSE))

2012-07-13 126.0730 145.8036
2012-07-20 126.1342 145.8616
2012-07-27 128.9303 148.6576
2012-08-03 129.7640 149.4975
2012-08-10 130.5752 150.2954
2012-08-17 132.3789 152.0963
```

<s>If you have PerformanceAnalytics loaded rollapply.xts will be dispatched instead of rollapply.zoo.  I edited to convert the object to `zoo` first to make sure the right `rollapply` is called.</s>

**EDIT:**

Thanks to some patching from [@JoshuaUlrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271616/joshua-ulrich), this now works with `rollapply.xts`,so you do not have to convert to `zoo`.  Also, `rollapply.xts` is now registered in the **xts** package instead of **PerformanceAnalytics**, so you will get the same results regardless of whether or not **PerformanceAnalytics** is loaded.  You'll need the under development version of **xts** -- Rev. 765 or later -- which is on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118).

```
rollapplyr(x, 750, a.ari.fun, by.column=FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow. I'm gonna try that, but... wasn't `by.column` needed just to deal with multivariate inputs? Or, at least, that was my thinking...

Comment: I get an error with that:

`> rollapplyr(data = x, width = 750, FUN = a.ari.fun, by.column = FALSE)`

I get

`Errore in xts(xx, tt, if (by == 1) attr(data, "frequency")) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)`

Comment: Do you perhaps have `PerformanceAnalytics` loaded.  Simply having that package loaded may cause problems here.

Comment: Yep.  That's the problem.  PerformanceAnalytics does not play well with others.

Comment: Ok, with a new session it works. Maybe you're right, it was `PerformanceAnalytics`, though it was not sufficient to detach it. Well, this is a some sort of issue: does one have to forget about using `PerformanceAnalytics` if he wants to make some back test?

Comment: I'm getting the same `NROW(x) must match length(order.by)` error and I do not have `PerformanceAnalytics` loaded. I'm on R 3.0.0 with `xts_0.9-3`.

Comment: @neverfox, update `xts`. The current version [on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) is 0.9-5.