# How to apply mean, sd etc. function to a whole matrix

Tags: r

I have the following `matrix`

```
Rho <- structure(c(1, 0.466666666666667, -0.866666666666667, -0.466666666666667, 
-0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 1, -0.6, -0.466666666666667, 
-0.333333333333333, -0.866666666666667, -0.6, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
0.466666666666667, -0.466666666666667, -0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
1, -0.2, -0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
-0.2, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("SPX Index", "MXE2 Index", 
"USG4TR Index", "FNAR Index", "DBLCMAVL Index"), c("SPX Index", 
"MXE2 Index", "USG4TR Index", "FNAR Index", "DBLCMAVL Index")))
```

I thought that, in order to apply functions to single matrix arguments (like rows and/or column), I had to use `mapply()` or `apply()` in several ways.

But, if I input

```
mean(Rho)  
sd(Rho)
```

this returns me separate application of functions:

```
> mean(Rho)
     SPX Index     MXE2 Index   USG4TR Index     FNAR Index DBLCMAVL Index 
   -0.04000000     0.01333333     0.06666667     0.04000000     0.12000000 
> sd(Rho)
     SPX Index     MXE2 Index   USG4TR Index     FNAR Index DBLCMAVL Index 
     0.7566006      0.6902496      0.7774603      0.6282250      0.5932959
```

This is not what I want: I want the mean and st. dev. of **all** the elements of my matrix, like

```
> mean(mean(Rho))
[1] 0.04
```

in just one command.

Is there a way to do it **without** coercing my matrix to vector/numeric/other?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4 xts_0.8-6                   
 [3] zoo_1.7-7                    gogarch_0.7-2               
 [5] fastICA_1.1-16               fGarch_2150.81              
 [7] fBasics_2160.81              rmgarch_0.97                
 [9] Matrix_1.0-9                 lattice_0.20-10             
[11] Kendall_2.2                  spd_1.7                     
[13] KernSmooth_2.23-8            rugarch_1.0-11              
[15] Rsolnp_1.12                  truncnorm_1.0-6             
[17] chron_2.3-42                 numDeriv_2012.3-1           
[19] MASS_7.3-18                  RcppArmadillo_0.3.4.2       
[21] Rcpp_0.9.13                  timeSeries_2160.94          
[23] timeDate_2160.95             rcom_2.2-5                  
[25] rscproxy_2.0-5              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] boot_1.3-5       grid_2.15.1      stabledist_0.6-4 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: `mean(Rho)` also works fine for me on the example matrix provided above but for `sd` one has to use `sd(c(Rho))`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424311/how-to-get-mean-median-other-statistics-over-entire-matrix-array-or-datafram

Comment: Coercing to vector (a la Ben's comment) really doesn't cost anything. Also, a warning: if you happen to have a list variable whose elements (columns) are of differing length,  mean(c(all_column_means)) will give you a weighted average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I cannot say for sure that this is the reason you're seeing what you're seeing without seeing your `sessionInfo()`, my guess is that you have the `PerformanceAnalytics` package loaded.

in the `zzz.R` file of that package, they have this code:

```
mean.xts <- function(x,...) {
if(is.vector(x) ||is.null(ncol(x))  || ncol(x)==1){
        x<-as.numeric(x)
        mean(x,...)
    } else apply(x,2,mean.xts,...)
} 
mean.matrix <- function(x,...) {apply(x,2,mean,...)} 

sd.xts <- function(x,na.rm=FALSE) {
    if(is.vector(x) || is.null(ncol(x)) || ncol(x)==1){
        x<-as.numeric(x)
        sd(x,na.rm=na.rm)
    } else apply(x,2,sd,na.rm=na.rm)
}
sd.matrix <- function(x,na.rm=FALSE) {apply(x,2,sd,na.rm=na.rm)}
```

I think it is awful that they do that and I've tried repeatedly to get them to change it, but to no avail.  Therefore, I boycott the package.

Anyway, start a fresh R session without loading that package and try again.

Comment: They (the authors) must have been "trained" on Matlab, which insists on doing this same dumb thing.  I have repeatedly had to teach colleagues (using Matlab) that just because `mean(mean(my_matrix))` works, it doesn't follow that  `stdev(stdev(my_matrix))` works.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I think it's that prior to **R** 2.14 (I think), the base **R** functions used to work on each column separately.  When that changed, it broke a lot of their code.  Instead of creating their own class, or editing their code to use `apply`, or talking the `xts` authors into adding a `mean.xts` and `sd.xts` method, they took the lazy route and just redefined the base function to its old definition.

Comment: @JohnGay, I see you've [had this problem before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12019358/967840)

Comment: You're right, GSee: it's like it happened in the linked question, it is a `PerformanceAnalytics` issue because I had it loaded; it's not the first time `PerformanceAnalytics` creates these issues. I think the best would be to load it just when needed and to detach it after use. I updated my question to show you `sessionInfo()`